# Prove that if $x$ is a fixed point for $g$ then its projection to $S$ minimizes $f$ over $S$.

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a convex and differentiable function and let $S$ be a nonempty, closed, and convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

The function $g:\mathbb{R}^n \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is defined by:
$$
  g(x) := -\big[ \nabla f\big(P_S(x)\big) - P_S(x)\big], \;\; \forall x \in \mathbb{R^n} \tag{1}
$$
Where $P_S(x)$ is the projection of $x$ onto the set $S$.

Prove that if $x$ is a fixed point for $g$ then its projection to $S$ minimizes $f$ over $S$.

---

**ATTEMPT**

Since $x$ is a fixed point for $g$ then we have $g(x)=x$.

Therefore rearrange $(1)$ to obtain:
$$
  \nabla f\big(P_S(x)\big) = P_S(x) - x \tag{2}
$$
**Case 1:** $(x \in S)$ 
We have that $P_S(x) = x$ and thus $\nabla f(x)=x-x=0$.

Since $f$ is convex then $x=\text{argmin}_{x \in S} f(x)$, as desired.

**Case 2:** $(x \notin S)$ 
It is possible to write $(2)$ as:
$$
  \nabla f\big(P_S(x)\big) = P_S(x) - x = d_S(x) = \inf_{s\in S} \Vert x-s\Vert \tag{3}
$$
Where $d_S$ is the distance relative to $S$.

---

I am frankly stuck, and unsure what to do. Moreover, it is not very clear to me how to use the closedness and convexity of $S$.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will focus on case $2$.

We will use the following result:

Suppose $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is non-empty and  convex, Let $h$ be a convex function, then $x^*$ is a global minimum if and only if $$\nabla h(x^*)^T(y-x^*) \ge 0, \forall y \in S.$$

Closeness of the set ensure that $P_S(x) \in S$.

We first establish a property of $P_S(x)$: $P_S(x)$ is the optimal solution to $\min_{z \in S}\|z-x\|^2$, hence by  the result, we have $$2(P_S(x)-x)^T(y-P_S(x)) \ge 0 ,\forall y \in S.$$

Let's now focus on the condition that $f$ being optimal on $S$ for our particular problem.  We have $\forall y \in S$,\begin{align}
\nabla f(P_S(x))^T(y-P_S(x))=(P_S(x)-x)^T(y-P_S(x)) \ge 0
\end{align}

Hence $P_S(x)$ is optimal.

Comment: Brilliant!
But doesn't your solution work for both cases 1 and 2? I think, if one considers your proof, then case 1 is useless, right?

Comment: I think it works.